# Let a string with linear density $\rho$ and tension $k$. Find $u(x,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, fourier-series, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

> Let a string with linear density $\rho$  and tension $k$ Its left and right hand ends $ [-\pi,\pi]$ are held fixed at height zero (Maybe not at $t=0$, but it are for $t>0$). 
>   Initial velocity $v_0(x)\equiv 0$ and
>   $u_0(x)=2\sin x$. Find $u(x,t)$

What I did

$\left\{\begin{array}{cccc}\dfrac{1}{c^2}u_{tt}&=&u_{xx}\hspace{0.25cm}x\in [-\pi,\pi]&\\
u_x(-\pi,t)&=&u_x(\pi,t)=0\\
u(x,0)&=&2\sin x\\
u_t(x,0)&=&0
\end{array}\right.$

$u(x,t)=\Psi(x)\theta(t)\\
u_{tt}=\Psi(x)\ddot{\theta}(t)\\
u_{xx}=\theta(t)\ddot{\Psi}(x)$

__

$\Psi(x)=e^{rx}\\
\Psi'(x)=re^{rx}\\
\Psi''(x)=r^2e^{rx}$

__

$r^2e^{rx}=-\lambda \Psi(x)\Rightarrow r=\sqrt{\lambda}i\Rightarrow \Psi(x)=e^{\sqrt{\lambda}i}\Rightarrow \Psi(x)=c_1\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\\
\Psi(x)'=-c_1\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+c_2\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\\
\Psi(\pi)'=-c_1\sqrt{\lambda}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)+c_2\sqrt{\lambda}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$

> My questions
>
> Am I doing it right? Now I don't know how to continue. Is there any
>   other way?

Comment: The wave speed in a tense string is $\sqrt{\frac{k}{\rho}}$, so plug that into your equation $\frac{1}{c^2} = \frac{\rho}{k}$

Comment: Thanks @NinadMunshi and then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All solutions to the $1$D wave equation are of the form

$$u(x,t) = f(x-ct) + g(x+ct)$$

where $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ are at least twice differentiable. Plugging in our boundary conditions we have that

$$u(x,0) = 2\sin x = f(x) + g(x)$$

$$u_t(x,0) = 0 = -cf'(x) + cg'(x)$$

Trivially, the solution is given by $f(x) = g(x) = \sin x$. We can check that this satisfies the last boundary condition as well, meaning that this problem had too many boundary conditions in the first place. Thus the final answer is

$$u(x,t) = \sin\left(x-t\sqrt{\frac{k}{\rho}}\right)+\sin\left(x+t\sqrt{\frac{k}{\rho}}\right)$$

Uniqueness means that any solution we guess that works has to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Laplace transform

$$
s^2U(s,x)+c^2U_{xx}(s,x)= s u_0(x) + v_0(x) = 2 s \sin x
$$

solving for $x$ we have

$$
U(s,x) = \phi_1(s)e^{\frac{sx}{c}}+\phi_2(s)e^{-\frac{sx}{c}}+\frac{2s\sin x}{c^2+s^2}
$$

with the boundary conditions $U(s,-\pi) = U(s,\pi) = 0$ we have

$$
U(s,x) = \frac{2s\sin x}{c^2+s^2}
$$

and after anti-transforming

$$
u(t,x) = 2\sin x\cos(c t)
$$

Comment: The solution you have for the differential equation in the Laplace domain doesn't seem to be right (plugging it back in does not satisfy the DE)

Comment: @NinadMunshi    "left and right hand ends [−π,π] are held fixed at height zero" $u(t,-\pi) = u(t,\pi) = 0$ and also $u(0,x) = 2\sin x,\ \ u_x(0,x) = v(0,x) = 0$. It accomplishes perfectly.

Comment: But it doesn't even satisfy the equation you have up there: $$U_{xx}(s,x) = -U(s,x) \implies s^2U + c^2U_{xx} = \frac{2s\sin x(s^2-c^2)}{s^2+c^2} \neq 2s\sin x$$

Comment: Put $u(t,x) = 2\sin x\cos(c t)$ into $u_{tt}-c^2 u_{xx}=0$

Comment: I'm not saying the conclusion is wrong, but your steps are completely invalid.

Comment: Do you know how the Laplace transform operates?

Comment: You haven't addressed the main issue from my earlier comment, the solution you have in the Laplace step *does not* satisfy the single variable ODE in $x$.

Comment: Let us introduce the necessary details then.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Please. See the attached details.

Comment: Aha I found the mistake! It was a simple typo in your equation after the Laplace transform step, there should be a minus in the differential equation, not a plus. Thank you for filling in the details, I would not have realized this was the issue had I not seen your homogeneous solution.